# How to change the old description, title and image shown from a site shared or liked on facebook for a new one?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

We have a site that has already been shared and liked on facebook before. This site has changed and we want to display a new logo, a new title and a new description when it is shared or liked on facebook, but it still displays the old information, even if the old title, description and image are no longer on the site.

We have tried adding the flowing code in the head but it doesn't work:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="image of the page" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title of the page" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="name of the page" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image of the page" />
```

Even with this code facebook keeps on showing the old information, is as if facebook has a cache that needs to be updated.

Any ideas on how to update this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try linting the website url in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). It should re-scrape with the new parameters.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I knew they had a cached version of my site. Thanks a lot!